# Checkstyle - return count in switch statement

Tags: java, checkstyle

Is it possible to change `ReturnCount` check to increase value for `switch` statements only? In docs, I cannot see it, but I am ready for a dirty hack or something.

I have

```
    <module name="ReturnCount">
        <property name="max" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxForVoid" value="0"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ReturnCount">
        <property name="max" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxForVoid" value="0"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="CTOR_DEF, LAMBDA"/>
    </module>
```

But for `switch` statements is it easier and cleaner for us to return multiple times (in most cases in each case statement) and this rule warns after 3.

Comment: Why not use a single return value at the end of the switch and assign the correct value in each case statement, followed by a break?

Comment: Exactly because of this - so many lines of boilerplate code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no existing option in `ReturnCountCheck` that will do what you want.

Since `ReturnCountCheck` supports xpath, you can use that to create an expression that will suppress the violations in the areas you wish to ignore. This would suppress the violation for the entire method and not limit the scope to just ignoring what is listed in the switches and violating on other parts of the same method.
See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionXpathFilter